# Combine Q objects in Django and limit one of them

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-q

I want to combine these 2 queries in 1 to get the `Music` object with name `xyz` and also get top 3 objects from genre `10`, ordered by artist:

```
1. Music.objects.filter(name='xyz', genre=10)

2. Music.objects.filter(genre=10).order_by('artist')[:3]
```

I can use `Q` objects like this but I don't know how to order & filter the 3rd `Q` object below:

```
Music.objects.filter( (Q(name='xyz') & Q(genre=10)) | Q(genre=10) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try like this?

```
Music.objects.filter( (Q(name='xyz') & Q(genre=10)) | Q(genre=10) ).order_by('artist')[:3]
```

Comment: This is incorrect. I want object with name `xyz` + top 3. This will simply get top 3. It won't ensure that the results have the object with name `xyz`

Comment: This is logically equivalent to `Music.objects.filter( Q(name='xyz') | Q(genre=10) ).order_by('artist')[:3]`

Comment: Also @click, there is now way to do it. You want four results that come from two different queries, why would you want to use a single query?

Answer (score 0):

No way to do it, use two queries but change second to avoid duplicates:

```
exact = Music.objects.filter(name='xyz', genre=10)
additional = Music.objects.filter(genre=10).exclude(name='xyz').order_by('artist')[:3]
do_something_with = list(exact) + list(additional)
```